# браузеры не видят файл javascript (видит только программа для написания кода)

Tags: javascript

При проигрывании кода из редактора `Brackets` - всё работает, функции вызываются.
Но если попробовать открыть `index.html` в браузере и вызвать событие, то браузер сообщает об ошибке - функция не найдена. Чего я только не пробовал и какую инфу не вкладывал в теги `script` - ничего не помогает, только Яндекс работает, все остальные браузеры не видят функцию или скрипты.

Код:

```js
function img_up(arg_src){
var div_all = document.createElement('div'); 
 div_all.id="div_all_id";        
document.body.appendChild(div_all);
        
var div_tx = document.createElement('div');
        div_tx.id="div_image";     
        document.body.appendChild(div_tx);
      div_tx.innerHTML="<img src="+" ' "+arg_src+" ' "+" onclick='img_dw()' >";
    }
                
                 function img_dw(){
    var remel=document.getElementById("div_image");
    remel.parentNode.removeChild(remel);
                     
    var rem_ove=document.getElementById("div_all_id");
    rem_ove.parentNode.removeChild(rem_ove);
    }
```

```css
    #div_all_id{
    
        position:fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: black;
        opacity: 0.7;
    }
    
    #div_image{
    
        position:fixed;
        background: black;
        color: red;

    } 
    #div_image img{
                    position:fixed;
        padding-left: 10%;
        padding-right: 10%;
        padding-top: 5%;
                    width: 80%;
    } 

    #galary{

    position: absolute;

    }
        #galary img{

    width: 200px;

    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="galary.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="galaryjs.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

<div id="galary">
       <img src="1.jpg" onClick="img_up(src)" >
       <img src="2.jpg" onClick="img_up(src)" >
  
</div>
        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: хотя тут вроде как работает, но непонятно почему не работает у меня на браузере. Сценарий прост -  галерея, нажимаешь на маленькую картинку, выходит большая картинка, на большую нажимаешь и она прячется остаются опять маленькие

Comment: Скрипты нужно подключать в конце документа, после `body`. Или использовать событие `DOMContentLoaded` / `window.loaded`

Comment: `onclick='img_up(this.src);'` так правильнее. И ещё совет, не используйте всякие программы для написания кода, который не требует компиляции. Достаточно будет текстового редактора `Sublime Text` или `Notepad++`

Comment: Скажите, в консоли разработчика файлы видны как подключенные? Во вкладке sources браузера Chrome, например

Comment: нет, файл JS не видно...все остальные на месте, спасибо что обратили на это внимание. Не знаю почему его нет в списке файлов

Comment: @Doofy не учите плохому

Comment: @PavelMayorov, где плохое? Если я в чём-то не прав или ошибся, покажи или аргументируй. А то написал чушь, трое заплюсили и ни один из четверых ничего не прокомментировал, а я сижу и думаю где не прав

Comment: тестил у себя локально, все работает. Возможно у тебя в настройках браузера отключен JS.?

Comment: в интернете - страницы работают нормально, вроде даже если скрипт в одном файле HTML тоже работает, а вот в отдельном файле - ниче не работает, только на яндекс браузере. ГуглХром не работает, интересно то что когда хром запускается от редактора кода Brackets - он нормально работает. А сам по себе открытый файл в браузере не видит скрипты

Comment: @Doofy, проблема в инлайновом обработчике и, возможно, в призыве использовать текстовые редакторы вместо нормальной `IDE`.

Answer (score 1):

Можно просто вызвать функцию прямо из консоли js
или выполнить

```
console.log('файл js подключен');
```

в файле galaryjs.js

Если оба варианта не сработают, значит неверно указан путь к файлу galaryjs.js